# Restrict actions based on User's auth status (e.g. logged-in, cookied, anonymous)

Tags: security, playframework

I am looking for ways to restrict certain actions in Controller(s) based on whether the user is logged in or not. I looked at the Security interceptor but how would the Security controller code know which action is being executed and what is its required access level?

I am looking for something like:

`@Auth-level("logged-in")`
`public static Member getProfile()`
`{`
`.....`
`}`

`@Auth-level("cookied")`
`public static void browseCatalog()`
`{`
`.....`
`}`

`@Auth-level("anonymous")`
`public static void contactUs()`
`{`
`.....`
`}`

Is this possible in Play? Or is there a similar solution for the problem above?

The way I did this in my Struts application was to use XDoclet to create a mapping from my Action classes comments and using a Servlet filter to examine the request and figure out if access is allowed or not. I was hoping for an easier way to do this in Play!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following documentation for the secure module as an example of an action/controller interceptor...

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/secure

Pay particular notice of the `@Check` notation, which gives you what you are asking for.